# How can i get mbeans name for jdbc connecion pool , GC Monitoring and others in websphere

Tags: websphere, grafana, jolokia

I want to start monitoring of websphere cluster in grafana tool by using jolokia. For that , mbeans and their attributes are required.For few of them like heap memory usage , thread count i have found by jconsole .

But didn't get  mbeans and attribute value to monitor for JDBC connection pool , garbage collection , thread count or others. Any idea how can i get that ?

Answer (score 0):

This Websphere documentation might help: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/index.html